# PostgreSQL service stops immediately after installing Windows Fall Creators Update 1709

Tags: postgresql, windows, postgresql-9.4, windows-10

The **server** itself runs fine with

```
pg_ctl -D <datadir> start
```

But the **service** stops immediately ("...Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs")

Access rights look OK, local system has full access to <datadir> and its parent directories.

Workaround is easy (manual start), but a service would be nice.

Tests with manual service starts (pg_ctl register) did not help.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4 and don't want some fresh or newer installaton since "it's just the windows service" and my version corresponds to installations on production servers.

No other changes.

1. functioning postgresql service
2. windows update 1709
3. service always stopping immediately

Nothing in logs, and pgevent.dll cannot be registered, neither with system32/regsvr32 nor with syswow64/regsvr32 (dllregisterserver entry point not found)

Any hints where I can continue searching for the underlying problem?

Note: I'm a domain user with admin privileges.

Comment: I'll update my PostgreSQL to 9.6 in the near future and I assume this problem will be obsolete afterwards, but atm it's still unsolved.

Comment: The question is now obsolete (and unsolved), since i had to update to 9.6 (what I'm doing by dumping, uninstalling, fresh install and dump imports). The fresh 9.6 installation has no windows service problems.